# confusion with POSIX permission, SUID and SGID

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, posix

I'm trying to understand the effectiveness of suid bit.

1.What is the difference between -rws------ and -rwx---rwx.?

2.Does other's must has exc permission to "inherit" the owner permission? -> for example:

-rws------  what is the meaning of this permission?

3.Lets imagine there exist an application her name is MyEditor.
MyEditor can edit other txt files.

-rwsr--r-x ed noOne MyEditor
-r--rw--w- ed noOne myText.txt

Lets assume there exist user that his is name is 'te', and he is not in noOne group.

does 'te' can edit myText.txt file using MyEditor?

Answer (score 1):

ls -l

-rw-r--r-x 1 root root 6118 May 16 14:05 editme.txt

The first "-" indicates that it is a file
The next 3 positions are of the user's name who owns the file
Then those are of the group owner's name
The last 3 are of others, ever body else

The the number 1, hard link count
The 1st root is the owner's name
The 2nd root is the group owner's name

So

1

-rws------ it is a file and the owner can read, write and execute( x not s)

-rwx---rwx it is a file and the owner can do all, group owner can do nothing, others can do all, a strange permission.

2
Execution permission is different from ownership. You can execute a file, and you don't have to be the file owner. As you can see in the "ls -l" example above.

-rw-r--r-x 1 root root 6118 May 16 14:05 editme.txt
I grant every one to have execute permission to the file (the last 3), but the owner and group owner ( first 6) can't.

3
So I think you can see you mistakes here now.

-rwsr--r-x ed noOne MyEditor -r--rw--w- ed noOne myText.txt

"Lets assume there exist user that his is name is 'te', and he is not in noOne group."

noOne in your example is not a group, 1st noOne is the owner of myText.txt, 2nd noOne I don't know what it is :v, and "ed". Do "ls -l" to see the output

1st MyEditor here is group owner. The app named MyEditor will have the permission of the user who execute the app, I guess.

The te user is in other (last 3), so it depends on how you config it.

--- --- r-- so te can read

--- --- --- he can't read

Some others stuff to google chown, chmod, chgrp, setfacl (access control list), soflink, hard link, inode, etc, LFCS

https://linuxhandbook.com/linux-file-permissions/